# Uploadify to use to upload files from server itself

Tags: php, uploadify

Is there a way to upload files directly from the server itself where the site is hosted. 
I really want to do that way cause all my old photo files are on the server and I want my uploadify to do grab those files directly from that server location specified. 
This will need frequently for my future use.

please give a solutions if uploadify support the same

Comment: can't you just move (`mv`) or copy (`cp`) them in shell?

Comment: sorry, I also need these individual file information to store in the database and use them dynamically in future. so that I prefer uploadify to do uploading and in the same time write details to database and do create thumbnails of photofiles also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploadify works just one direction: client -> server. You simply can use ftp or sftp to download your photos if that task you only need to do once.